# How do I get the process name and binary path for a open port with Qt on Windows?

Tags: windows, qt, service, port, netstat

I'm writing a port collision checking function.
I need to determine:

- if a certain port is open
- the process name of the daemon
- path of the binary of the daemon

My idea was to run a QProcess executing the native command `netstat -abno` and parsing the output. But the parameter `-b` requires elevated rights (UAC) and i don't want to bug users with an UAC prompt.

Is there a Qt lib out there providing such functionality?
How would you implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by port path? Frankly, looking at the title, I was thinking about serialport without seeing the body...

Comment: With port i mean a communications endpoint, like ports: 80, 8080, 5433.

Comment: I know what a port is :) but I do not know what a port path is and why you need that :)

Comment: "port path"? I mean the path of the executable of the daemon listening on a certain port. I changed the question accordingly. Why? I need the path to check, if the executable/daemon is running from our installation folder or from another dir.

Comment: Easy to do on Windows.  Not without elevation, this is very exploitable information.

Comment: @Jens : Have you ever found a solution to the "... path of the binary ..." part? My current knowledge is that you cannot determine the binary of a process without elevation, but maybe you found something?

Comment: Nope. Accessing this info needs elevation. I ended up with an application startup check and a shutdown dialog, which asked the user of the monitoring tool to restart as admin or grant elevated rights by altering the executable settings to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Tcpvcon.exe` which is part of [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)
*TCPView* Needs admin rights, *tcpvcon* does not
use with `-an` or `-acn`
you can even specify the application to check afterwards: e.g. `Tcpvcon.exe -an Skype`

originally found by [Dane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2929/dane) some time ago:

> Use TCPView if you want a GUI for this. It's the old Sysinternals app that Microsoft bought out

Answer (score 1):

- My idea was to run a QProcess executing the native command netstat -abno and parsing the output

To do this you can just:

```
QProcess cmdProcess;
...
cmdProccess.start(..);
while(cmdProcess.waitForReadyRead(-1)) someParseFunction(cmdProcess.readAllStandardOutput());
```